# SQL: create table from another WITHOUT populate the new table

Tags: sql

Is there a way to create a new table based on an existing one (select) without populating the new table with data from the existing one?

example, this query populates the new table:

```
CREATE TABLE tempTable NO PARTITION AS 
    ( SELECT 
    TRIM(COMPANY_ID) AS COMPANY_ID 
     FROM
         {schema}.table2
    FOR READ UNCOMMITTED ACCESS IN SHARE MODE );
```

Thanks.

Comment: Which SQL engine?

Comment: Depends on the database, try adding condition will never be true? `FROM
         {schema}.table2 where 1=0`

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, you can do

```
SELECT *
INTO NewTable
FROM OldTable
WHERE 1 = 0
```